# PHPExcel gera arquivo .xslx corrompido

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, phpexcel

Quero gerar um arquivo `.xlsx`, com os registros que não foram importados, de uma outra tabela `.xlsx`, porém consigo gerar o arquivo `.xls` sem problemas, já quando tento gerar `.xlsx`, o Excel avisa que o arquivo está corrompido.

*Segue o código:*

```
$php_excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
      ->setCellValue('A' . $linha_php_excel, $row[CPF])
      ->setCellValue('B' . $linha_php_excel, $row[NOME])
      ->setCellValue('C' . $linha_php_excel, $row[NR_CONTRATO])
      ->setCellValue('D' . $linha_php_excel, $row[DATA_CONTRATO])
      ->setCellValue('E' . $linha_php_excel, $row[PRODUTO])
      ->setCellValue('F' . $linha_php_excel, $row[OBS_CONTRATO])
      ->setCellValue('G' . $linha_php_excel, $row[PARCELA])
      ->setCellValue('H' . $linha_php_excel, $row[VALOR])
      ->setCellValue('I' . $linha_php_excel, $row[VALOR])
      ->setCellValue('J' . $linha_php_excel, $row[OBS_PARCELA])
      ->setCellValue('K' . $linha_php_excel, 'Registro já existe');
$php_excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('K' . $linha_php_excel)
      ->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED);
$linha_php_excel++;
```

#### `Header`:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($php_excel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="teste.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Internamente os arquivos .xls e xlsx são diferentes. Só o fato de você trocar a extensão de um arquivo .xls válido para .xlsx já impede o Excel de abrir-lo.
O xlsx entre outras coisas, "zipa" o conteúdo. A biblioteca que está usando suporta esse formato de arquivo?

Comment: Suporta, utilizo a classe PHPExcel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geralmente monto header depois monto o $objWriter e ainda utilizo  **ob_end_clean();** para limpar qualquer erro de corrompimento e após  isso que exporto o arquivo excel.

Ficaria assim...

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="teste.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($php_excel, 'Excel2007');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Desse jeito funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda, @thiagofred, sabe algum jeito, que eu possa fazer pro download acontecer em outra página, tipo gravar em uma $_SESSION a $php_excel, e em outra página, fazer o download da tabela?

Comment: Nunca fiz isso e não sei se funciona, mas tenta criar uma $_SESSION com o $objWriter e faça o download dele em outra página. Talvez dê certo.

Comment: Não funcionou, vou pesquisar sobre isso.

Comment: mas na página que você buscou o dado da $_Session["$objWriter"] você fez o include da função PhpExcel para fazer     $objWriter->save('php://output');   quando solicitado?

Comment: Sim, voltou a dar o aviso de que o arquivo está corrompido, quando utilizo a $_SESSION, acho que a única forma de fazer é gravar cada $row na $_SESSION, e na página que quero fazer o download, montar o .xlsx.

Comment: Pode ser... ou gravar na sessão o $php_excel, para depois montar o header e exportá-lo em outra página.